# Connecting an armature to a model and using Weight Paint

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I've been working on a low-poly Mandalorian character model in Blender, and I'm currently setting up an armature. However, I don't know how to connect the armature to the model so I can move parts around, nor do I know how to use weight paint to make sure parts don't get dragged. What do I do? Also, I need to know how you mirror the armature in a way where you can move bones from either side without moving the parallel part.

Here is Imphenzia's tutorial, at the part I'm stuck on...
https://youtu.be/szIvkd1NBz4?t=875

And here's the file I'm working on...

[image]

Update: Here's where I am for Weight Paint...
[image]

Comment: Probably best to watch Imphenzia's tutorial on [Rigging low poly characters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw) first if you've not done any rigging before!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have named the bones correctly with a *.L*-suffix you can create the bones on the right side with the *Symmetrize* command. Select the *Armature* object, switch to *Edit* mode, select the bones and choose *Armature > Symmetrize* to create the missing bones.

[image: symmetrize the rig]

Then you just need to parent the *Armature* with the *Cube* mesh (your model). Make sure the *Armature* object is the active object (selected last). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and choose *With Automatic Weights*.

[image: parent mesh and armature]

Finally, switch to *Pose* mode and rotate the bones. Or grab the heels to lift the legs and test the IK constraints.

The cloak needs extra bones or manual weight painting else it moves with the legs.

**Update**

After a closer look at your updated file, it looks like there are a few more issues. The weights are fine. Your mesh looks black in *Weight Paint* mode and "invisible" grey when you edit other objects because it has 6(!) *Mirror* modifiers on it. Besides this, there are a few other things you should fix:

- remove the *Mirror* modifier, just keep one.
- apply the *Scale* to the armature and the mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) in *Object* mode
- remove 37 duplicated vertices of the mesh (<kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* in *Edit* mode)
- the armature has mirrored bones for the spline and head because you gave these bones accidentally a *.L* (or *.R*) suffix. Give the suffix only bones that you want to mirror such as the shoulder, pelvis, arms & legs bones.
- the root and the control bones (IK leg controller and poles) have the deform option enabled. Enable this option only for bones that actually deform the mesh (see bottom right on the screenshot below).
- the bone rolls might be not consistent. If you rotate the arm and hand bones in T-pose the arm bends horizontally but the hand turns vertically (Yoga pose).
- for the cloak, you need to add three extra bones as you see [in the video](https://youtu.be/szIvkd1NBz4?t=879).
- todo: IK controller for the hands

If you fixed these issues then the parent operation *With Automatic Weights* works fine and you don't need to paint the weights manually.

[image: screenshot 3]

[image]
<sup>Blend file with the fixes</sup>

Comment: Now I need to know where I should apply weight paint, and how much?

Comment: I'm trying to look for weight paint, but I can't find it.

Comment: The Ctrl+P *With Automatic Weights* operation does the weight paint for you. If you want to check the result go to *Weight Paint* mode (Ctrl+Tab, 7). In the *Object Data Properties* (the green "triangle" icon on the right side of the screen) you will find the *Vertex Group*. Scroll through the list and you will see the weights for each bone. Each bone has its group. Alternatively, you can see the weight numbers in edit mode and with overlay visualize them: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/vertex_weights.html

Comment: I don't see a green triangle icon nor any Vertex Group information.

Comment: I'm on Weight Paint now. I now need to know where I should paint.

Comment: Here's the file, and where I am on for Weight Paint mode. What do I do now? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=WJGjbB5J" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WJGjbB5J/)

Comment: The weights are fine but you have 6 mirror modifiers active. That's the reason why the model looks black in weight paint mode. And there are some other issues. I've updated my answer above. The blend file is included. Have a look at it. I hope this helps you. The [green "triangle" icon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html) is visible in *Object* mode when you have selected the mesh. There you find the vertex groups.

Comment: Is that file from pasteall.org safe to download? Will I get any viruses from that if I download it?

Comment: pasteall.org is used here to share blend files. It is not more secure and not less secure than other popular file hosters. Blend files are usually safe but *can* contain harmful scripts. Blender gives you [a security warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phmj0.png) before the script is executed and you need to confirm it. Of course, it's recommended to *deny* this with the *ignore* button when you have downloaded the file from the internet.

Comment: Should I go and download the fixed Mandalorian Blender file from pasteall.org then?

Comment: It's up to you ;-) If you feel better I will upload it to blender.exchange.com .... done.

Comment: You can upload that file to Blender.exchange. It'll be safer for my laptop.

Comment: It's already uploaded. See answer above